# Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When using Visual Studio 2010, I open an aspx and cs file to edit. (I have not created a project. I am simply opening one aspx file and one cs file from my web directory to edit.) The intellisense will not detect System.Web or a large variety of others. In fact, only basic resources seem available. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: You've kind of answered your own question: use a project

Comment: @AndrasZoltan Are there intellisense settings that would allow for me to have it always use System.Web and others as part of it's list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are not in a project, you lack much of the context that would permit full intellisense support. VS has no idea what assemblies are included, and does not have imports from the web.config.

Remember that Intellisense tries to only present you with code completions that actually apply in the current build configuration. Without assemblies referenced, it can't guess that you have anything at all in, say, System.Web.

Comment: Are there any settings that would allow me to force intellisense to recognize certain namespace regardless of imports?

Comment: Sure. Those "settings" are the project files. I'm not being a smart ass; That is literally what enables VS to give you Intelligent Intellisense.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. I don't tend to like the structural setup for VS, it includes a lot of bloat configs that are unnecessary for me, so I create my own construct and just edit the files. Guess I'll have to do without intellisense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the Intellisense pretty much based on the content of the "using" clauses you have in the beginning of your file. It runs based on what you have already typed against a list o possible functions contained on the "used" assemblies.

For example, if you want intelisense to have access to the `Convert` function you need to use the `System` assembly. Without it, intelisense wont know the function exists

Comment: The issue is that it isn't even recognizing System.Web in the using directive. @AndrewBarber seems to have the right idea on the problem. Just wish there was a way around it.

Comment: The usings are only half the story; what assemblies are referenced also matters. For instance, without System.Configuration refernced, Intellisense knows nothing of ConfigurationManager.